# Any ideas on class isn't instantiating in Magento for the correct event firing (SMTPPro event vs. test event)?

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering if anybody might have some advice for me on why I've got an event observer class that is instantiating just fine when I tie it to *controller_action_predispatch*, but does absolutely nothing when I'm tying it in to *aschroder_smtppro_before_send*, which is where I need it to work.

I don't want to end up skipping on doing this the Right Way, and override something in *Zend_Mail*, instead, but I'm getting a little desperate after the amount of hours that I've spent trying to figure out why this isn't working at all, when tied to the correct event.

All of this is regarding implementing a very simple blacklist of domains to intercept and block transactional email (handled through *SMTPPro* on our server) to the applicable domains.  I mean, eventually.  Right now it's just test code, as you can see following.

**config.xml follows**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
        <Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <helpers>
        <emailblacklist>
            <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Helper</class>
        </emailblacklist>
      </helpers>
      <models>
        <myorganization_emailblacklist>
          <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Model</class>
        </myorganization_emailblacklist>
      </models>
      <events>
        <!-- <controller_action_predispatch> -->
        <aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
          <observers>
            <myorganization_emailblacklist>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>myorganization_emailblacklist/observer</class>
              <method>watchEmails</method>
            </myorganization_emailblacklist>
          </observers>
        </aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
        <!-- </controller_action_predispatch> -->
      </events>
    </global>
  </config>
```

**app/code/local/Myorganization/Emailblacklist/Model/Observer.php follows**:

```
<?php
class Uselite_Emailblacklist_Model_Observer {
    public function watchEmails(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent();

        //echo "<pre>";
        //die(var_dump($order));
        Mage::log('Damo\'s debugging info order:\n' . var_dump($order) .
            '\n debugging info observer:\n' . var_dump($observer), null,
            'd4m0log.log');
    }
}
```

Any help that you might be able to offer, or even pointers in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

-Damon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try **aschroder_smtppro_template_before_send** instead of aschroder_smtppro_before_send ? As far as I know, this extension overrides the E-Mail Template engine.

Comment: Hadn't tried that previously, no.  Thank you for the information.  I haven't had time to do a whole lot with it, since tying to that specific event, but it _is_ breaking now when it hits the event call, so I've got more to work with, if nothing else.

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like I'm able to very easily find what is breaking this in the logs now.  I'm not getting an error page; just the chromium 'Aw, Snap!' something went wrong page.  I can't find log entries anywhere that will tell me what might have happened to cause this.  Any ideas where I might be able to find something of the sort, @webster?

Comment: Are you still trying to log the whole $observer object? Perhaps this is a bit too much because it's a huge object. In your observer try something like this instead `Mage::log('observer is up and running', null, 'd4m0log.log');`. Then have a look at your log file to see, if something happens.

Comment: I was, yes, and it looks very much like this may have been part of the problem.  Now that I'm not doing a `var_dump` on anything, it's seeming pretty kosher.  So that helps me a lot with what I'm doing, but I still need to be able to find out what's in `$observer` and `$order` in order to see what I have to tinker with.  Any suggestions where I can get a better way to dump those or perhaps just some good documentation on them?  Thank you so much for the great feedback and willingness to discuss! _votes up_

Comment: Have a closer look at the file app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php. You will find a piece of code `Mage::dispatchEvent('aschroder_smtppro_template_before_send', [...]`, this is where the event is dipatched. The variables in the following array can be accessed in your observer via e.g. `$observer->getEvent()->getTemplate()`. So if you want to get the order object, you have to hook into some other event, e.g. _checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_